# Is there a function for accessing the amount of elements that have a value in an std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, std

In C++, assume I have an `std::array<std::optional<std::int>, 5> array`. Let's say I set the first 3 elements to be of a certain value. Is there a function that when passed `array` returns 3 (i.e. Returns the number of elements that has an **assigned** value)? Or is there anyway to improve the std::array so that it supports this functionality? I appreciate your help.

P.S. Guaranteed: The array's elements are always consecutive.
For instance,

```cpp
std::array<std::optional<std::int>, 5> arr;
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 4;
cout << func(arr) << endl; // Returns 4 in this case
```

Edit 1. I already knew about `std::count`, but I do not know how to check if an element is defined. Also, the array could be of any type.

Edit 2. What if I used std::optional? How could I do that, then?

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count

Comment: Is your array sorted?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin No. Any array could work.

Comment: @Brian How do I use `std::count`?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean. An array cannot have entries that do not have a defined value. The number of entries with defined values is the number of entries.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I meant "An element that is set", updated the question.

Comment: @IanChiang If you mean a `std::int` that has no particular value, then there is no way to check if a value is nothing in particular.

Comment: So your question is `I do not know how to check if an element is assigned` ?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Then is there any way to improve my data structure?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Yes. Sorry for the inconvenience. Updating the question.

Comment: You can switch to an `std::unordered_map` or `std::map`

Comment: @IanChiang If there's no value that you'll never set things to that you can use to indicate unset, then use `std::optional<std::int>`. You may be able to use zero or a large negative number to indicate unset.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So you mean the data structure should be `std::array<std::optional<std::int>>`?

Comment: @IanChiang Exactly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The number -1 never appears, but how do I check it?

Comment: @IanChiang Initialize every entry to `-1`. Then just use `std::count` (or a simple loop) to count the number of entries that aren't `-1`.

Comment: Use `std::count_if`

Comment: You might want to check for `fixed_vector` or something like that. It will allow resize, but only on the stack with a fixed max size preallocated.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: An array of size N has N elements in it, period.  If you want to have space for 5 ints, but only want to actually only have 4 ints in that space, you want `std::vector` or something like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I already knew about `std::count`, but I do not know how to check if an element is defined.

You can use `std::count_if()` for this, eg

```cpp
std::array<std::optional<int>, 5> arr;
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 4;
auto cnt = std::count_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
    [](const auto &elem){ return elem.has_value(); }
);
std::cout << cnt << std::endl; // Returns 4 in this case
```

Comment: The `elem::has_value()` function is interesting. I will use that in future applications. Thank you very much! +1.